# Is the file winmon.sys a virus in windows/system32/drivers folder? Please help me out of this problem

Tags: windows, virus

Windows
Can someone help me with this file, my pc was infected with a lot of viruses lately, and I then installed antivirus-> avg free and it detected a lot of viruses (20-30 viruses) and deleted them all. And now after a few days, it is reporting this file winmon.sys in the windows/system32/drivers folder, IDK if its okay to delete this file with antivirus. I have scanned it on virustotal and 51 out of 72 engines says its virus, should I safely delete it? As I have read online that its some windows internal files. I'm totally confused now about this issue.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,winmon.sys has been considered as one of the most dangerous OS threat. It usually infect all famous browser by attaching add-ons, plug-ins and other suspicious code. By modifying browser setting and attacking your browser, it will lead you to the third-party site and start to cause interruption while surfing the web. It secretly gets installed into the PC without asking for their approval and cause lots of serious troubles for them. The primary goal of its developers is to boost web traffic, promote sponsored products or services and earn online revenues.
The process known as winmon.exe belongs to software Multimedia AV Controller by unknown.
Winmon.exe is not essential for Windows and will often cause problems. Winmon.exe is located in the C:\Windows\System32 folder. The file size on Windows 10/8/7/XP is 110,080 bytes. https://www.file.net/process/winmon.exe.html
It is a file with no information about its developer. The program is not visible. You can uninstall this program in the Control Panel. Winmon.exe is not a Windows core file. Winmon.exe is able to monitor applications. Therefore the technical security rating is 51% dangerous.

Uninstalling this variant: If you run into problems with winmon.exe, you can uninstall the program using the Control Panel ⇒ Uninstall a Program ⇒ Multimedia AV Controller.

For more information:
https://www.file.net/process/winmon.exe.html
http://fix-computervirus.blogspot.com/2018/06/delete-winmonsys-successfully-how-to.html